# Document Mode changed to Quirk when opening a new tab on IE (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, window.open, quirks-mode

I have a button click event that do some server side job and finally open a new tab. But when that happens, the parent tab on Internet Explorer become very bizarre. Then I found Document Mode is changed to Quirk mode that make the whole website move to left instead of centre and I lost some styling as well. I tried with the code below but still happen.

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Can anyone tell me why that is happening and how to solve this? Thanks.

My code sample.

```
    Sub btnTeachersView_Click
    ........ server side code ........
    Response.Write("<script>")
    Response.Write("window.open('../abc.aspx','_blank')")
    Response.Write("</script>")
    End Sub
```

NOTE: It needs to be on server side coz there are other jobs need to be done first and my client wants it in a new tab so i can't just redirect to that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap your `<script></script>` tags in the correct `<html></html>` tags with doctype etc. I think that might be the problem that triggers quirks mode, the lack of proper dtd

Comment: Hi Onkelborg, actually your code does solve out the problem .. but i already changed all the code and rewrote it in new way .. and forgot to check out this post. Thanksss

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. The only workaround I could find was to navigate to a blank location then set the value to location that you desire. Like so:

```
var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
newWindow.location = '../abc.aspx';
```

And in VB:

```
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("var newWindow = window.open('','_blank');")
Response.Write("newWindow.location = '../abc.aspx';")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

Comment: Sorry Dylan .. making that doesn't help for me. Thanks,